# How to loop .iloc index values in pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, loops

I have two dataframes, where one dataframe has 2 columns with 11 rows and another dataframe with 2 columns with 2 rows.

```
print(df)
```

Output is :

```
    C1  C2
0   1   1
1   2   2
2   3   3
3   4   4
4   5   5
5   6   6
6   7   7
7   9   9
8   11  13
9   10  11
10  12  11
```

Second dataframe is

print(df1)

Output is :

```
    Mean Dev
0   2    0.5
1   1    1.0
```

I'm trying to subtract each and every value from column 1 of df with 1st column 1st row Mean value and divinding with 2nd column 1st row Dev value. Below is the code

```
for i in range(0, len(df)):
    print((df['C1'][i] - df1.iloc[0][0]) / (df1.iloc[0][1]))
```

Output is :

```
-2.0
0.0
2.0
4.0
6.0
8.0
10.0
14.0
18.0
16.0
20.0
```

My question is how to perform the subtraction and dividing for every column with respect to the Mean and Dev columns. For example, i'm trying to write code

```
for i in range(0, len(df)):
    print((df['C1'][i] - df1.iloc[0][0]) / (df1.iloc[0][1]))
    print((df['C2'][i] - df1.iloc[1][0]) / (df1.iloc[1][1]))
    print((df['C3'][i] - df1.iloc[2][0]) / (df1.iloc[2][1]))
    print((df['C4'][i] - df1.iloc[3][0]) / (df1.iloc[3][1]))
```

**Can anyone say how to loop the .iloc values, so that the code will become easier**

Comment: This seems very similar to [How to iterate two or more columns and perform analysis in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69542118/15497888). Is there a particular reason for this separate question from a new account?

Answer (score 0):

Try to generate column names like C1, C2 dynamically and use one print statement and loop through all columns

```
import pandas as pd

data = [[1,2,3,4], [2,3,4,5], [3,4,5,6],[4,5,6,7]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['C1','C2','C3','C4'])

data1 = [[0.1, 0.2], [0.2,0.3], [0.3,0.4],[0.4,0.5]]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns = ['Mean','Dev'])

for i in range(0, len(df)):
    for j in range(0,len(df.columns)):
        colName = 'C'+str(j+1)
        print((df[colName][i] - df1.iloc[j][0]) / (df1.iloc[j][1]))
```

output

```
4.5
6.0
6.75
7.2
9.499999999999998
9.333333333333334
9.25
9.2
14.499999999999998
12.666666666666666
11.75
11.2
19.5
16.0
14.25
13.2
```